# self.after doesn't wait when passing value

Tags: python, timer, self, pyserial, function

I'm making a gui in python wich uses the serial port for sending commands. In my old script, without a gui, i used time.sleep(x) between the write commands (it is necessary for to commands to succeed). Now when i use a gui envrimont, i can't use sleep so i use after.

It works well, but:
I'm using Tkinter for my gui. When i press the button start , OnButtonClickSTART starts the other function after x time. With self.after i wait x secondes between every process. It works, but when i give a value with the function, it doesn't wait the given time.

```
   def OnButtonClickSTART(self):
            print "START"
            self.button1.configure(state='disabled')
            self.after(1000, self.waitmore)

    def waitmore(self):
            value = 5
            print value
            self.after(10000,self.waitmuchmore(value))
    def waitmuchmore(self,value):
            print value
            self.after(10000,self.OnButtonClickSTOP)
    def OnButtonClickSTOP(self):
            print "STOP"
            self.button1.configure(state='normal')
```

And isn't here a better way to execute a series of command , with a certain time between them. Like sleep, but works with 1 function and doesn't disable the gui.

Thx

Comment: It seems the time you have given in self.after has a constant value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `self.waitmuchmore(value)` will immediately call the `waitmuchmore` method. You need to use either a [`lambda` expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) or [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to return a new function that will call `waitmuchmore` with `value`, and pass that to `self.after` instead:

```
lambda: self.waitmuchmore(value)
```

or

```
import functools
functools.partial(self.waitmuchmore, value)
```